# Accessing class members using reference_wrapper instead of standard pointers in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, vector, reference-wrapper

I am trying to build an `unordered_map` to `vector` variables which are members of my class. I can do this using standard pointers `*` but this requires the use of `(*x)` to access the vector. I wondered if `std::reference_wrapper` would be cleaner, but can't get it to work.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

class model_class {

private:

  static constexpr auto MaxHerds = 1 ;
  static constexpr int MaxInitValues = 5 ;
  static constexpr int MaxAnimals = 2 ;

  std::vector< double > MamCellsF ;
  std::vector< std::vector< double > > InitCond ;

public:

  std::unordered_map< std::string , std::reference_wrapper< std::vector< double > > > vector;
  std::unordered_map< std::string , std::vector< std::vector< double > >* > array;

  model_class ( ) :
    // initialise vectors
    MamCellsF( MaxHerds , 0.07 ) ,
    InitCond( MaxAnimals , std::vector< double > ( MaxInitValues , 0.7 ) )
  {
     // point to variables from model
     vector.insert({"MamCellsF", std::ref(MamCellsF)});
     array["InitCond"] = &InitCond;

     // assign to vectors
     MamCellsF = { 0.001 , 0.002 }  ; // warning: automatic resizing
     InitCond = { { 1.0 , 550 , 3.5 , 1 , 4 } ,
     { 2.0 , 625 , 3.5 , 5 , 4 } } ;
  }

  void print_values(){

    // access the vectors
    double a = vector["MamCellsF"].get()[1]; // error: "no matching function call to `std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<double>>::reference_wrapper()"
    double b = (*array["InitCond"])[0][1];
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;

  }

};

void test()
{

  model_class model;
  model.print_values();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vector["MamCellsF"]` returns a reference to the value in the map. So if there isn't one it must be constructed first. That uses default constructor but `std::reference_wrapper` is not default constructible hence the error.

I think that STL containers are safe with T that are not default constructible but their operations might be limited. So I don't recommend that.

Comment: I thought I have already inserted the reference into the map.

Comment: @SimonWoodward That doesn't matter. This is compile error, because in that operator is code that does the adding and the default construction and it cannot be compiled.

Comment: Are you saying that `std::reference_wrapper` is not the right tool for what I am trying to do? Is it ok to use standard pointers then?

Comment: @SimonWoodward It has the sematics that you want, but the cost to it is that it's not default-constructible and STL containers don't work nicely with that. So I would stick to pointers probably.